# How to determine whether number has digits in ascending order from right to left

Tags: c++

I need to determine whether an entered number has digits in ascending order from right to left.

My code seems not working correctly

Here is my code:

```
int n, temp;
cout << "Please enter number: ";
cin >> n;
bool ascending = true;
temp = n%10;

while (n>0)
{
    n /= 10;
    if (temp < n % 10)
    {
        ascending = false;
    }
}

if (ascending)
{
    cout << "Number is ascending";
}
else {
    cout << "Number is not ascending";
}
```

Comment: In situations like this, it is best to use a debugger. Debuggers can be intimidating for beginners, so the quick alternative is to stick in a few `cout`s to keep updated on the values of variables and where the control flow is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not updating the value of `temp` after every iteration

```
int n, temp;
cout << "Please enter number: ";
cin >> n;
bool ascending = true;
temp = n%10;

while (n / 10 > 0)
{
    n /= 10;
    if (temp > n % 10)
    {
        ascending = false;
        break;
    }
    temp = n % 10;
}

if (ascending)
{
    cout << "Number is ascending";
}
else {
    cout << "Number is not ascending";
}
```

Comment: You can also `break` after setting `ascending = false`.

Comment: @Thirupathi Thangavel oh ye right, thank you, but it still not output correct answer, for example for number "5321" - output is not ascending

Comment: @Andrew Check now

Comment: @Thirupathi Thangavel still the output is not correct

Comment: "ascending" or "ascending consecutively?  the answer is correct for the former but not for the latter.

Comment: @Thirupathi Thangavel Thanks a lot! Now it working! But can you explain, why without dividing in while loop its not working? like this while(n>0)

Answer (score 1):

When I run the latest from Thirupathi, it does work.  Note OP said ascending order **RIGHT to LEFT**.

Ex output runs:

```
./order
Please enter number: 5321
Number is ascending

./order
Please enter number: 2356
Number is not ascending
```

Comment: Can you suggest a fix? Otherwise this is not an answer.